# Is it possible to search MySQL for data encrypted by CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, encryption-symmetric

I am building an application that includes PII (e.g. telephone number) encrypted using CakePHP's Security Utility. I've patterned my code after the custom database [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261210/5593769) by @ndm -- so AES-256 encryption is taking place at the application level and then gettingpassed to a MySQL database. This is working great but I'm not sure how to implement search.

I understand that I cannot do fragment comparison (eg `LIKE %%`), but expect that it is possible to search for an exact match. However because `Security::encrypt` returns a different string each time it's used, the following will not work:

```
$query = $this->Users->find('all')
    ->where([
        'telephone' => Security::encrypt($search, Security::getSalt())
    ]);
```

I searched for similar questions and [found one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823051/how-to-select-256-bit-salted-encrypted-values-from-mysql) in which the accepted answer was to create additional columns containing string hashes for each encrypted column (elsewhere this is called a [blind index](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql)). I would prefer not to modify my database but can do so if this is the only solution.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Right, making a hash for searching is the only way. Otherwise you'd have to fetch _all_ the rows, and search them one by one, by decrypting the telephone data and comparing it to your plaintext search criteria.